# simplecov: extract coverage percentage

Tags: ruby, simplecov

I run simplecov like this

```
# test/test_helper.rb
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start do
  add_filter "/test/"
  coverage_dir "/tmp/coverage/"
end
```

Instead, or in addition to printing this

```
Coverage report generated for Unit Tests to /tmp/coverage. 30 / 31 LOC (96.77%) covered.
```

How can I tell ruby/simplecov to save the number 96.77 to an env variable or file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I came up with

```
SimpleCov.at_exit do
  IO.write('/tmp/result_tests_coverage', 'work-in-progress')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a hacky mess, but it's what works for me. (This is in bash, calls the command that generates the coverage, and has the % sign in the file...)

```
<command>  | tee -a log/coverage.log
coverage_string="$(grep "Coverage report generated" log/coverage.log)"
[[ "$coverage_string" =~ ([[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\%) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} > percent.txt
```